# Java external property on Wildfly

Tags: java, properties, jboss, wildfly

Actually, I have this code to get a folder with properties

```
Properties props=System.getProperties();
String path = props.getProperty("jym.classpath");
```

And the **"jym.classpath"** is defined on **Apache Tomcat console -> Java -> Java Options**, like:

> -Djym.classpath=C:\JAVA_SYS\props\jym\props

I want to do the same on a **JBoss Wildfly 8.2**, without doing it on my code, since I need to keep the properties separated

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by editing the **standalone.conf** file, and adding:

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djym.classpath=C:/MUNDO_JAVA/projects/jym/dev/props"

I still didn't know why I had to edit that file, and not the **standalone.conf.bat** since I'm running on Windows, and I've read that the **standalone.conf** is for Unix.

Comment: You could add a system property too with the following CLI command: `/system-property=jym.classpath:add(value="C:/MUNDO_JAVA/projects/jym/dev/props")`. Also if you're using `standalone.bat` then you should be editing `standalone.conf.bat`.